# Logout codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a logout controller in codeigniter :

```
<?php

class Logout extends MY_Controller {

    function index()
    {

        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect('index.php');
    }
}
```

This logs me out but when i call another controller after logging, like "/site/addnewpost",
this just logs me in again, as if the sassion had not been destroyed previously. Why is this happening?

Comment: remove the redirect. make another script that contains only `var_dump($_SESSION)` and call that script after logging out to check if the session really is destroyed

Comment: what is your login part? (in which you check for session)

Comment: @xbonez - Correct me if I'm wrong here, but I thought CodeIgniter does not use the native PHP session.

Comment: @Tyil you're right, $_SESSION won't surely be set here as CI doens't use it. I hope OP is not mixing them both too!

Comment: ah, my bad. I use Codeigniter, but always use `$_SESSION` manually. Wasn't aware CI maintains its own session variables

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Follow ALex's suggestion, but using CI code:). What I mean, try unsetting each session data individually. I read once about an issue in version 2.0.3 I think, but I don't remember now and I don't have time to search for the reference. It's in their forum, though, and the suggestion was the same: unset each session element one by one.

```
$this->session->unset_userdata('data_one');
$this->session->unset_userdata('data_two');
$this->session->unset_userdata('data_three');
$this->session->unset_userdata('data_one');
$this->session->sess_destroy();
redirect('home','refresh');  // <!-- note that
//you should specify the controller(/method) name here
```

You *need* to redirect because CI's session are just cookies, not the native php session array.

Another thing...make sure the fault isn't in your login methods, which logs you in no matter if you succesfully logout or not!

Answer (score 2):

Try explicitly delete items like this:

```
$this->Session->delete('User');
$this->Session->destroy();
$this->Cookie->delete("User");
$this->Cookie->destroy();
$this->Auth->logout();
$this->redirect('whereever');
```

Answer (score 1):

My problem had to do with caching on the server side.  The quickest I could fix it was by appending random text to the logout link:

```
<?php
    $this->load->helper('string');
    echo anchor('/home/logout/'.random_string(), 'logout');
?>
```

home/logout contained the same code as `function index` in the question.

Just so you know the `redirect('/', 'refresh')` did not work for me, but I again I did a quick test.

I am guessing that the `random_string()` method can be replaced by outputting headers that force cache to be cleared etc. As you have probably guessed, I can't do that right now as I am super busy.  Maybe later.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try manually setting your "logged_in" or whatever you called the session to false. Then, destroying all other session data.

```
    $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', FALSE);
    $this->session->session_destroy();
    redirect('index');
```

Answer (score 0):

first we have to load session library to deal with session than unset the sessionID and destroy the session. I am using this code to unset my session and secure logout.

```
$this->load->library('session');
$this->session->set_userdata('user_id', FALSE);
$this->session->sess_destroy();
$this->load->view('your URL');
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers.  Include some explanation of what you have changed, why it works, etc.