# codeigniter login and user session

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, authentication

I built an user login to my site by this guide:
http://www.iluv2code.com/login-with-codeigniter-php.html

I have few question about session's

I need to put the session_start(); in every controller or there is a way in codeigniter that it will automaticlly be in all controllers? (should I do that?)

and there is a other way rether to put in every function that:

```
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
    {
       //function code
    }else{
     //If no session, redirect to login page
     redirect('../login', 'refresh');
   }
```

or should I do that for every controller function (for example if I have controller named page and he have the functions :index,edit,view I need to put it for every one of them?

and last question, I have logout button on the top of every page called by view/header
should I also put this function:

```
 function logout()
 {
   $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in');
   session_destroy();
   redirect('home', 'refresh');
 }
```

in every controller or I can do it a "golbel" function in some way?

EDIT:
I use this in hooks.php:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Hooks
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
| This file lets you define "hooks" to extend CI without hacking the core
| files.  Please see the user guide for info:
|
|   http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html
|
*/

$hook['post_controller_constructor'] = array(
                                'class'    => 'SessionData',
                                'function' => 'initializeData',
                                'filename' => 'loginHelper.php',
                                'filepath' => 'hooks',
                                'params'   => array()
                                );
and this in loginHelper.php:
<?
class SessionData {
    var $CI;

    function __construct(){
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
        if(!isset($this->CI->session))  //Check if session lib is loaded or not
          $this->CI->load->library('session');  //If not loaded, then load it here
    }

    function initializeData() {
          // This function will run after the constructor for the controller is ran
          // Set any initial values here
          if(!$this->CI->session->userdata('logged_in')){    //call session methods with super object
            redirect('../login', 'refresh');    
          }else{
            $data['user'] = $this->CI->session->userdata('logged_in');
          }
    }
}
?>

    /* End of file hooks.php */
    /* Location: ./application/config/hooks.php */
```

the user['data'] not created in all the pages. where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For your second question about logout, I usually put the `logout` function in a `User` controller and call it as `<a href="<?php echo base_url().'user/logout';?>">Log Out</a>`.

For your first question, I saw a tutorial how you do user login in a controller and extend that controller in your regular controller, thats how you avoid login check in every function. I am trying to find that tutorial, once I get it, I'll share it, but the concept is like that way.

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to put the `session_start();` in every controller!

You could simply start the session class in the `autoload.php` file in your `config` directory!

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session', 'encrypt');
```

Also, it is better to check if the user is logged in, inside the constructor function of the classes!

```
if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
    redirect('loginController/loginFunction', 'refresh');
```

and to destroy all the sessions when logging out, you could use `sess_destroy();`

Answer (score 0):

**Initializing a Session**

To autoload Session, open the `application/config/autoload.php` file and add the item you want loaded to the `autoload` array so: `$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');` Yo don't use `session_start();` and  `session_destroy();` at all.

- Session Documentation:
  https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html
- Auto-loading Resources:
  https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/autoloader.html

**To Check Login**

Use [Hooks](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html) to avoid chunky code dupplications and it is better practise. Navigate bottom of the page and read *Hook Points* so you get an idea. It is easy! Definitely learn hooks.

**Logout**

You answer [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616887/logout-codeigniter).

Comment: The hooks do a problem for me. I did everything like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850247/use-session-data-in-hook-in-codeigniter-2-1-0 but I get this problem: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: SessionData::$session

Filename: hooks/loginHelper.php

Line Number: 17


Fatal error: Call to a member function userdata() on a non-object in /home1/site/public_html/subdomain/application/hooks/loginHelper.php on line 17

Comment: If I was you I would place a few echo lines to identify what is/isn't being processed to debug. I guess your helper needs to be refactored.

Comment: Remove session checking from the __construct() and add session to autoload like I defined above.

Comment: it's not working. (also the redirect not work) it's look like the hook don't do nothing (turn it to TRUE on config)

Comment: You need to refactor your code and probably the logic.

Answer (score 0):

After alot of working I solved the problem with the login check.

I didn't use the hooks. I build a MY_Controller in core folder and exteds it in all my controllers expect from the login controller.

In the MY_Controller I use thie login check.

CodeIgniter core controllers:
https://philsturgeon.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-Base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY/